# phpfmt breaking code in class variable definitions

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with phpfmt.

When I define a class-variable like:

```
class ClassNameHere
{
    private static array $__counter = [];
}
```

it gets formatted to

```
class ClassNameHere
{
    arrayprivate static $__counter = [];
}
```

This obviously breaks my code.
The only solution I found so far is not use the type-hint.

Does anyone know which phpfmt-pass is responsible for this or if its a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The current version of `phpfmt` [does not support](https://github.com/kokororin/vscode-phpfmt/issues/91) class property type hinting. You will need to use a different PHP formatter. I recommend trying [PHP Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode) it provides basic code formatting, IntelliSense and some more features.

Comment: You answer could be improved by providing some information about alternative options.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I added a recommendation in the answer. It was my first time writing an answer.